# Using Fluid StandaloneView (also FluidMail) in CLI context

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

The name and description of `StandaloneView` (*"Should be used as view if you want to use Fluid without Extbase extensions"*) suggests, that it is possible to use this view anywhere outside of any Extbase context. E.g. for CLI tasks such as generating emails (`FluidMail`) or using the view to generate HTML code which is than transformed into a PDF.

Unfortunately none of the above works if the template references assets such as images or CSS/JS files.

The reason is, that the view relys on a request-object to derive the domain-relative paths to the assets, which is obviously not working in CLI as no proper request-object exists:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Request prototype object
   format => protected "html" (4 chars)
   pluginName => protected "" (0 chars)
   controllerExtensionName => protected NULL
   controllerSubpackageKey => protected NULL
   controllerObjectName => protected "" (0 chars)
   controllerName => protected "Standard" (8 chars)
   controllerActionName => protected "index" (5 chars)
   arguments => protected array(empty)
   internalArguments => protected array(empty)
   dispatched => protected FALSE
   originalRequest => protected NULL
   originalRequestMappingResults => protected NULL
   method => protected "GET" (3 chars)
   requestUri => protected "http:///var/www/html/vendor/bin/typo3cms" (40 chars)
   baseUri => protected "http:///va/typo3/" (17 chars)
   isCached => protected FALSE
```

The view-helper will create wrong URIs like this:

```
// f:uri.resource(path:'Css/pdf.css', extensionName: 'myext')
<link href="typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/Css/pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" />

// f:image(src:'EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Images/logo.png')
<img src="/va/typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/Images/logo.png" />
```

The solution given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054403/fluid-standalone-view-in-be-context) does not help, as the template file is rendered/found, but the linked assets are missing which messes up the template completely.

What is a possible solution for this issue? Or: how to work with the `StandaloneView` in a proper way? Since even the core `FluidMail` has this issue, it seems to be a general conceptional problem.

Appreciate any input, idea or solution!

**PS:**
To embed any recourses into the template is no solution!

Comment: If you won't embed resources but want them to be displayed in a mail, where should the email client take them from? You have two options: a) embed them or b) load them from a public URI. The first option you do not want, for the second, you have to tell Fluid, that you want absolute URIs, so they could be loaded from outside your website.
https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/master/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Image.html#absolute

Comment: I was guessing that mentioning the mail will lead to this answer ;-) True, to load linked sources they have to be available through a public URL, which is still hard because the CLI has no domain request context. And the other case - using the SingleView template for PDF processing - is pure internal and linking to external resources seems like a workaround again... So its impossible with the current implementation?! (except introducting tricky hacks like faking a ServerRequest or so)

Comment: CLI has no domain request context, right. This can not be resolved by TYPO3, because of the missing information which domain should be used.  There's no chance to choose it automatically. The only way is to manually set the domain when calling via CLI or to configure somewhere in your extension.
How are you generating PDFs? TYPO3 cannot do this. So, maybe, it's not a missing feature of FluidStandaloneView but of the library, you are passing the generated HTML to?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, will see how I work around this. I'm using the mpdf/mpdf library which just receives a bunch of ready-rendered HTML code, which is working great as long as the Fluid ViewHelper can determine the paths. Means: as long as I trigger the PDF generation throught a web-request, the PDF looks like it should, but through CLI the CSS/Images paths are wrong like described above, resulting in a plain HTML default styling messed-up PDF.

Answer (score 1):

For people having the same issue und looking for a solution I'll sum up what I already had in mind and what was confirmend by Julian (thanks). If anyone comes up with a better solution, feel free and apprechiated to share.

**Solution 1:** avoid linking of assets in templates which should be used in CLI contexts and embed all the needed resources inside the template.

**Solution 2:** faking a ServerRequest with a domain, to allow the ViewHelpers to determine the correct paths for liked assets.

**Solution 3:** using the BaseUrl helper function of [base-url](https://github.com/sitegeist/base-url) extension

**Solution 4:** write custom ViewHelpers (or better extending the common ones) which determine the paths to assets not only from the request object, but from the TYPO3 instance path if running as CLI, which should be enough for internal processing.

Still, the name `StandaloneView` is pretty missleading IMO concidering all the unexpected trouble using it e.g. in CLI context.